# Need help understanding script syntax

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm new to Python, and while reading a script, I encountered the following syntax:

```
def approximate_random_effects(data, labels, group):

    correlation_per_donor = {}
    for donor_id in set(data[group]):
        correlation_per_donor[donor_id], _, _, _, _ = \
          linregress(
            list(data[labels[0]][data[group] == donor_id]),
            list(data[labels[1]][data[group] == donor_id]))
    average_slope = np.array(correlation_per_donor.values()).mean()
    t, p_val = ttest_1samp(correlation_per_donor.values(), 0)
```

Why does the LHS of `correlation_per_donor[donor_id]` have `_,` and why does the RHS have so many `()` with consecutive `[]` nested inside it? I do not understand it and even running through Codeacademy's lists/dict tutorial it did not help.

Advice is needed, thanks!

EDIT: Is my comprehension of the script correct? Attached below:

```
for each donor ID,
```

for-loop picks out donor_id in group residing in DATA:

LHS has 5 variables, but only makes `donor_id` a part of a dictionary "`correlation_per_donor`"

RHS does `linregress` on 2 lists, with (labels[first item] in DATA, group in DATA == donor_id) and (labels[second item] in DATA, group in DATA == donor_id)

## I don't understand why == donor_id is required

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm actually targeting that bunch of nested [] too.

Comment: Yeah, but it's better with one question per question.

Comment: 1. Ask one question at a time. 2. Do your research (SO, official docs, etc.) *before* asking.

Comment: `linregress` expects two values taken from `list` which is a 2-dimensional array where the 2nd index is a bool (hence the `==`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` is just a variable name, in this case used to say "I'm ignoring this data".

The right hand side has `[]`'s because it's a nested data structure of lists and dictionaries.

Comment: What would "I'm not ignoring this data" look like then? Do i fill it up with ` correlation_per_donor[donor_id]`? I know this script is highly specific, but i hope you can narrow it down so i know what to look for, thanks!

Comment: You would have a variable name there, which is then used further down. `correlation_per_donor[donor_id], foo, bar, l, q` f ex.

Comment: Alright thanks @Lennart! Do you mind verbally describing what that RHS side does though? I'll post what I understand from it in my question, will edit in a min.

Comment: The RHS side does a LOT, what exactly is unclear?

Comment: `data[group] == donor_id` will return True if data[group] equals donor_id. Hence `foo[data[group] == donor_id]` will pick different items from `foo` depending on what donor_id is.

Comment: I'd recommend you to pick apart the right hand side but by bit into separate variables, so you can see what it does. As it is no it's not good programming.